# Set default launcher flags when I run ng test without additional arguments

Tags: angular, karma-runner, angular-test, karma-chrome-launcher

I need to pass custom argument to chrome in order to set locale: --lang en-US

I've done it using customLauncher. My src/karma.conf.js:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
    ],
    customLaunchers: {
      ChromeHeadlessLang: {
        base: 'ChromeHeadless',
        flags: [
          '--lang en-US', // ensure that the test works on all environments with the same locale
        ]
      }
    },
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    ...
  });
};
```

And I can run it using

```
ng test --browsers ChromeHeadlessLang
```

However, I would like to use the lang flags by default, without specifying --browsers

```
ng test
```

**Can I override the default flags, so that they are used when I run just `ng test`**?

Comment: What about browsers: ['ChromeHeadlessNoLang']?

Comment: @AntonRusak: Sorry, that was a typo in the question. I basically want to make sure that when somebody runs `ng test` it will always use the same language, independent of their local OS or chrome settings

Comment: browsers: ['ChromeHeadlessLang'] should do

Comment: @Liero did you find the fix? I'm running into a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the default behavour of any script in your `package.json`. Just add it to your `scripts` object like this:

```
"scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "test": "ng test --watch=false --whateverParamYouWantToAddHere",
    },
```

Comment: I know, but most angular developers just run `ng test` not `npm run test`, because that is how the angular docs mentions it. Anyway, it does not answer the question

Comment: It depends on what you use as package manager. For `npm` yes you're right. In my project I use `yarn`. You can then directly call `yarn test` and it will execute the script from `package.json`. Unfortunately `npm` is a bit dumb in that sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify default values for all parameters of `ng test` inside `angular.json`

e.g.:

```
 "test": {
          "builder": "ngx-build-plus:karma",
          "options": {
            "codeCoverageExclude": ["src/*.ts"],
            "codeCoverage": true,
```

All available parameters: https://angular.io/cli/test